# How to show add region-specific link endings in google search results?

Tags: search, region

When someone google searches "Twitter", the link in the search results changes depending on what country the user is in.

For example, someone in Korea will see: 
twitter.com/?lang=ko

while someone in Britain will see:
twitter.com/?lang=en-gb

How do I make it so the ?lang="country" shows up in google search results for my website?

Comment: This actually tells Twitter Servers that the language they have to show the user is either British English or Korean. Why do you need it? (I am not a Web developer, My guess is that it runs some sort of language localization script. But thats just my guess)

Comment: But we can safely say that it is not region specific string. It is preference specific string.

Comment: Because our site has users from all over the world, so we want the site to show in their specific language in google search results.

Comment: I see. Then I suppose you will find these very useful. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html , 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en
 , http://searchengineland.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-multilingual-and-multiregional-seo-157838